# Inverse image of a closed interval is compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f: D\to R$ is continuous with D compact. Prove that {$x:0\leq f(x)\leq1$} is compact.

I believe the idea behind this problem is to prove that {$x:0\leq f(x)\leq1$} is closed, since any bound and closed set is compact, by the Heine-Borel Theorem, and it is clearly bounded. I'm just not sure how to prove that it is closed. I know you start with an arbitrary accumulation point of the set and proof that it is an element of the set as well, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$f^{-1}([0,1])$ is closed since $f(x)$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$.

> **Notice that any closed subset of a compact space is compact :)**

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that $D$ is compact.

Comment: @5xum: Do you notice that $D$ is compact in the OP?

Comment: what exactly does $f^{-1}([0,1])$ mean?

Comment: @jlang The *preimage* of $[0,1]$. If $f:X\to Y$ and $A\subseteq Y$, then $f^{-1}(A) = \{x\in X: f(x) in A\}$.

Comment: @jlang $f^{-1}([0,1])=\{x\in D: 0\le f(x)\le 1\}$.

Comment: So the preimage is a subset of [0,1]? I don't think we have discussed this in my class so I'm not exactly sure if this is what my professor is looking for in this proof.

Comment: @jlang: No, the preimage of [0,1] under $f$ is a subset of $D$.

Comment: Is there some theorem stating that the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function, f, will be a closed set as well?